# Parsing WSDL with PHP SoapClient

Tags: php, xml, soap, wsdl, soap-client

I am trying to consume a SOAP web service with PHP.

The web service WSDL can be found [here](https://eu1.praxedo.com/eTech/services/cxf/v6/BusinessEventManager?wsdl).

Simply creating the client like that:

```
try {
    $wsdlUrl = 'https://eu1.praxedo.com/eTech/services/cxf/v6/BusinessEventManager?WSDL';
    $client = new SoapClient($wsdlUrl);
}
catch(Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

This fails with the following error:

> **SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Unknown required WSDL extension 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy'**

I tried using 2 separate generators:

- https://github.com/WsdlToPhp/PackageGenerator
- https://github.com/wsdl2phpgenerator/wsdl2phpgenerator

They both fail with the exact same error.

PHP version is `7.0`

I found [this old bug report](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=46130) from 2008 which apparently never got fixed because not enough info was submitted at the time.

Does anyone know how I can fix that issue?

Answer (score 1):

If you look at your WSDL you will see it imports a WS-Policy section:

```
<wsdl:import location="https://eu1.praxedo.com/eTech/services/cxf/v6/BusinessEventManager?wsdl=Pxo-policies-v1.0.wsdl" namespace="http://ws.praxedo.com/policies/v1.0">
</wsdl:import>
```

See http://specs.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy/ws-policy.pdf for details:

> The Web Services Policy Framework (WS-Policy) provides a general purpose model and corresponding syntax to describe the policies of a Web Service. WS-Policy defines a base set of constructs that can be used and extended by other Web services specifications to describe a broad range of service requirements and capabilities.

It's probably on this that your code generator chokes, although I don't know why; these policies apply at execution time. If you have difficulties generating the code because of them, you could remove that import from the WSDL and try to generate the client code without the policies. You basically download the WSDL to a local file, delete that import line above, and feed this modified local WSDL file to your code generators and your SoapClient.

You will still need to respect the policies when calling the SOAP web service (for example, [the service requires basic authentication](https://eu1.praxedo.com/eTech/services/cxf/v6/BusinessEventManager?wsdl=Pxo-policies-v1.0.wsdl)), but the generated client code should be the same with both versions of the WSDL.

As mentioned in the other answer, you also need to use SOAP 1.2 since the binding in the WSDL is defined as SOAP 1.2 (the SOAP Envelope will have this namespace `xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"`).

Comment: I tried removing that line but the error remained. I tried removing further lines and/or parameters from the WSDL (in particular the one with *http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy*) and in the end the generator was able to generate the code. But it is unusable. I am running into (many) other errors while trying to use the generated classes. I tried debugging but failed so far. I am in touch with the web service provider to try and find another solution (in other words I'll give up trying to use their web service with PHP - they do have a SDK in Java...). Thanks for your help anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this is available on 7.0 but try setting the option `soap_version` to `SOAP_1_2` (see the [docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/soapclient.construct.php)).

Comment: That did not help. Same error after passing `['soap_version' => SOAP_1_2]` in the client options.

Comment: Hmm well an ugly hack would be to build a simple script/controller to do the request to get the WSDL, set `required` to false on the extension and output it again. After that change the url in the constructor to point to that script or route from the controller.